# Understanding LM723-based variable-voltage power supply schematic

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, voltage-regulator, power-electronics

This is the schematic of the [PS-1502dd power supply](https://uydudoktoru.com/dosyalar/elektronik/Besleme_Devreleri/) ([actual schematic image](https://uydudoktoru.com/dosyalar/elektronik/Besleme_Devreleri/ps1502d-0-15v-ayarli-1-5v-7-2v-kademeli-guc-kaynagi-semasi.jpg)), which uses an [LM723](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/LM723) to create variable output voltages.

I am having trouble understanding how this power supply works. According to the datasheet, Vref produces some fixed reference voltages that can be used as a reference to control the output voltages. However, in this schematic, the reference voltages are applied to the slider pin of the potentiometer, and Vin+ is connected across it. I'm unsure about how the highlighted circuitry works.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the diagram shown the key resistor is missing. You need to add a 7.5k (R6) resistor between "+" (Vp) input and GND. Also, 3.9k (R3) resistor is missing as well.

http://arduinotehniq.blogspot.com/2019/06/chinese-power-supply-ps-1502dd-15v2a.html

We can redraw the circuit just to show one output voltage range (6V).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fT0q9I.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now finding the output voltage is easy because we have differential amplifier.

$$V_{OUT} = V_{REF} \left[\left(\frac{R_6}{R_6 + R_5 + (1 -\alpha) R_4} \times \left(1 + \frac{R_1}{R_3 + \alpha R_4|| R_2} \right)\right) -\frac{R_1}{R_3+\alpha R_4}\right]$$

Where:
\$\alpha =\$  is a \$R_4\$ POT wiper position from 0 to 1.

Comment: Yes, this answer helped me a lot. When we add the R3 and R6 resistors, this circuit makes sense. I have verified that these resistors exist in the actual hardware. This was the actual answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

> *I'm unsure about how this highlighted circuitry is functioning.*

Just simplify by redrawing and focussing on the 0-15 volt range: -

[image]

All those resistors and pots and switches can be replaced by one pot (call it the 0-15 volt range coarse control and fine control combined). Then, it boils down to the regulation kicking in when the voltage on Vin- equals the voltage on Vin+.

Of course there is an added complication with all the other ranges slightly modifying each other's settings but, in a nutshell it boils down to what I drew. I will also add that the designer chose a pretty tortuous approach to the switches and, I think, the design evolved from the main pot setting I show above to adding the other ranges. If you started from scratch you'd do this in a way that the different switch settings didn't interact with each other.

---

Just in case anyone is wondering why another answer is suggesting a resistor is missing; they are incorrect. Despite Vin+ being connected via the potentiometer, it will always receive Vref and, as the wiper approaches Vin-, the output voltage regulation point lowers towards 0 volts. Why the "designer" originally took this approach is open to speculation and, my speculation is that the design evolved in a bit of a hit and miss way until they found something that worked.

Answer (score 2):

Figure 5 on my version of the datasheet shows a regulator configured for an external PNP pass transistor.  I think that is basically what you have, with the 2N3055 added as a current booster.

The voltage reference is applied to a switched bank of adjustable voltage dividers.  These apply various percentages of the reference voltage to one input of the error amplifier.  The other input comes from the output through the R29/R10 node.

Overall, the circuit has a variable voltage (the switched attenuators) applied to a fixed-gain amplifier.  If you redraw the circuit using only one set of output adjuster components, the circuit operation might become more clear.

Comment: The two transistors form a PNP Sziklai pair.